# How to fix Firebase collection() error in Vue.js component using Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

Cant connect to firebase:
my code in init.js:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey:.. ,
  authDomain: ,
  projectId:..
  storageBucket: ..
  messagingSenderId: ..
  appId: ..
  measurementId:,
};


initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore();
export { db };
```

then in a component (I know it should be in vuex but im just trying to check it):

```
import { collection, addDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import db from "../firebase/init";

async addQuestion() {
      const colRef = collection(db, "Questions");
      console.log(colRef);
```

and i get:
*Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore
FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore*

in firestore a have a collection namde Questions

I tried all diffrent ways and i dont really understand where is a problem?

I tried all diffrent ways and i dont really understand where is a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are importing wrong, try to change it to:

```js
import { db } from "../firebase/init";
```